# Unable to Post data to WebApi using Jquery from html5

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, html, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem to posting data to WebaPi controller using Jquery ajax in html page .. when i test through fiddler it's coneected and working fine , but when i try to using Ajax it give error only..

**here is my sample code ..**

```
var bookData = {
                "CurrentCompany": "BizSight Sample Product Company",
                "CompanyName": CompanyName,
                "LegalName": "Biztech",
                "Address1": Address1,
                "Address2": Address2,
                "City": City,
                "State": State,
                "Phone": Phone,
                "ZipCode": ZipCode,
                "Fax": Fax,
                "Email": Email,
                "Website": Website,
                "CountryID": 1,
                "federalTaxID": 1,
                "CurrentUser": CurrentUser,
                "BusinessType": BusinessType,
                "CurrentFiscalYear": Jsondate
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "http://77b2130d5c3446eea4e4210c51529230.cloudapp.net:8080/Create/",
                data: JSON.stringify(bookData),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                processData: true,
                success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                        var result = JSON.stringify(data);
                    $("#loading").show();
                    alert("success..." + result);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    $("#loading").show();
                    alert("Test3:" + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
```

When i post data from html and check fiddler it give message like below image

[image]
am i missing anything in this code..? fiddler it self  it's working but frmo html page not working .. can you please help me how to resolve and achieve this

**My Api class** `

```
public class CreateController : ApiController
{
    public static string CompanyName = " ";
    public static string con;
    public static string sqlConnection;
    public static string DatabaseName;
    string TrustedConnection = "Yes";
    string DBServer = " ";
    string FilePath = null;
    string testFirstline = " ";
    //clsLog objLog = new clsLog();
    bool isSuccess = false;




    public string Post(DatabaseCls cls)
    {
        string ReturnMessage = "Success";

        // ReturnMessage = "Hello  " + id + "_" + parameter1 + "_" + parameter2 + "_" + parameter3 + "_" + parameter4 + "_" + parameter5 + "_" + parameter6 + "_" + parameter7 + "_" + parameter8 + "_" + parameter9 + "_" + parameter10 + "_" + parameter11 + "_" + parameter12 + "_" + parameter13 + "_" + parameter14 + "_" + parameter15;
      return ReturnMessage;
    }}
```

Thanks 
Victor .A

Comment: are you sure you need to do this : `data : JSON.stringify(bookData),`

Comment: Can you show the error you are getting, the webAPI method and the class you are trying to serialize into? If the method is found when calling it from ajax but you are getting an error then most likely your object will not serialize into the type you have specified or your webAPI has not been set up to allow CORS requests.

Comment: @timothy , i need to pass json data to my api .. is there any alternate ..?

Comment: @Stephen , it does not give any message except  error string only..... but when i test fiddler post method became Option ..

Comment: Ok the options error you see is the CORS issue I was referring to, Your API has to be set up to allow cross site requests.

Comment: @Stephen, I have updated my original Query added my API class, can you please check my API class..

Comment: If you are getting an OPTIONS error then CORS is your problem (I have an answer below for this). I'll update my answer with a suggestion for your api method as well.

Comment: @VictorAthoti. i'm not sure what your handler is expecting. not stringifying the data will result in them being posted as separate POST variables.

Comment: @Timothy, Then how can i post my data to APIController ..can you please guide me ...

Answer (score 1):

The OPTIONS error you are seeing is because of CORS. You need to add this to your WebAPI in the Startup.cs to allow cross site requests.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

    var formatters = configuration.Formatters;

    //-- Disable XML support
    formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();

    var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
    jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json-patch+json"));
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
}
```

(edit, suggestion)

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class CreateController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost, Route("create")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]DatabaseCls cls)
    {
        try
        {
             return Ok(new { success = true });
        }
        catch
        {
             return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  url: "http://77b2130d5c3446eea4e4210c51529230.cloudapp.net:8080/api/Create", //note the additional "api" in url
  data: JSON.stringify(bookData),
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
       var result = JSON.stringify(data);
       $("#loading").show();
       alert("success..." + result);
   },
   error: function (xhr) {
       $("#loading").show();
       alert("Test3:" + xhr.statusText);
   }
});
```

Comment: It's in System.Web.Http, If you can't add it then you can just remove it and change your route to this: [HttpPost, Route("api/create")]

Comment: Hi Stephen , This is not helping to me.. i tried same thing what you suggest me .. it gives 415 exception when i check in fiddler...

Comment: You may just need to allow json in your webApi. I edited the answer to show this. Also, when using fiddler you need to specify the content type. Content-type: application/json

Comment: I would also look into a free app called Postman which is much nicer for testing your api than fiddler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94198/discussion-between-victor-athoti-and-stephen-brickner).